# How to properly save Common Lisp image using SBCL?

Tags: common-lisp, dump, sbcl, quicklisp

If I want to create a Lisp-image of my program, how do I do it properly? Are there any prerequisites? And doesn't it play nicely with QUICKLISP?

Right now, if I start SBCL (with just QUICKLISP pre-loaded) and save the image:

```
(save-lisp-and-die "core")
```

And then try to start SBCL again with this image

```
sbcl --core core
```

And then try to do:

```
(ql:quickload :cl-yaclyaml)
```

I get the following:

```
To load "cl-yaclyaml":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    cl-yaclyaml
; Loading "cl-yaclyaml"
.......
debugger invoked on a SB-INT:EXTENSION-FAILURE in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {100322C613}>:
  Don't know how to REQUIRE sb-sprof.
See also:
  The SBCL Manual, Variable *MODULE-PROVIDER-FUNCTIONS*
  The SBCL Manual, Function REQUIRE

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [RETRY                        ] Retry completing load for #<REQUIRE-SYSTEM "sb-sprof">.
  1: [ACCEPT                       ] Continue, treating completing load for #<REQUIRE-SYSTEM "sb-sprof"> as having been successful.
  2:                                 Retry ASDF operation.
  3: [CLEAR-CONFIGURATION-AND-RETRY] Retry ASDF operation after resetting the configuration.
  4: [ABORT                        ] Give up on "cl-yaclyaml"
  5:                                 Exit debugger, returning to top level.

(SB-IMPL::REQUIRE-ERROR "Don't know how to ~S ~A." REQUIRE "sb-sprof")
0]
```

Alternatively, if I try:

```
(require 'sb-sprof)
```

when sbcl is started with saved core, I get the same error. If sbcl is started just as `sbcl` there is no error reported.

In fact, pre-loading QUICKLISP is not a problem: the same problem happens if sbcl is called initially with `sbcl --no-userinit --no-sysinit`.

Am I doing it wrong?

PS. If I use roswell, `ros -L sbcl-bin -m core run` somehow doesn't pick up the image (tested by declaring variable `*A*` before saving and not seeing it once restarted).

PS2. So far what it looks like is that sbcl does not provide extension modules (`SB-SPROF`, `SB-POSIX`, etc.) unless they are explicitly required prior saving the image.

Comment: Maybe you want to describe the problem. For example by providing a reproducible test case and a copy of an actual error message.

Comment: @RainerJoswig I've expanded the question. I hope it provides more information.

Comment: One more update: it seems this is the feature of SBCL: CCL's `SAVE-APPLICATION` works as expected. Does SBCL do some tree-shaking when saving the image?

Comment: What OS and what version of SBCL are you using? I can't reproduce the problem on Linux + SBCL 1.3.2.

Comment: @jkiiski Ubuntu + SBCL 1.3.2 as well. But, considering it is in `/usr/local/bin/`, it is not the one provided by the distribution. I think it was a binary from SBCL website.

Comment: @jkiiski @RainerJoswig I found the problem! SBCL's core is looking for `contrib` directory with extra modules (including `SB-SPROF`, `SB-POSIX` etc.) **in the same directory where the core is**. And if they are not pre-loaded at the time of saving the image, SBCL doesn't put them into the image. I wonder if this is the behaviour of a particular SBCL version or all of them?

Comment: Do you have a `SBCL_HOME` environment variable set?

Comment: Actually, I don't. And now I see (section 1.2 of installation instructions) that SBCL primarily looks for `contrib` in `SBCL_HOME` or where the image resides. Thanks!

Comment: I found it is possible to save result of the (sb-int:sbcl-homedir-pathname) into a global variable and to restore it when image started, using sb-ext:*init-hooks*

```
(defvar *home*
  (sb-int:sbcl-homedir-pathname))

(defun restore-home ()
  (setf sb-sys::*sbcl-homedir-pathname*
        *home*))

(pushnew 'restore-home sb-ext:*init-hooks*)
```

Comment: Oh, here is example code with load hook: https://gist.github.com/svetlyak40wt/00ceaa4118609555d1630e3d500050b6

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks for the help from @jkiiski here is the full explanation and solution:

1. SBCL uses extra modules (`SB-SPROF`, `SB-POSIX` and others) that are not always loaded into the image. These module reside in `contrib` directory located either where `SBCL_HOME` environment variable pointing (if it is set) or where the image resides (for example, in `/usr/local/lib/sbcl/`).
2. When an image is saved in another location and if `SBCL_HOME` is not set, SBCL won't be able to find `contrib`, hence the errors that I saw.
3. Setting SBCL_HOME to point to `contrib` location (or copying `contrib` to image location or new image to `contrib` location) solves the problem.
4. Finally, about roswell: roswell parameter `-m` searches for images in a specific location. For SBCL (`sbcl-bin`) it would be something like `~/.roswell/impls/x86-64/linux/sbcl-bin/1.3.7/dump/`. Secondly, the image name for SBCL must have the form `<name>.core`. And to start it, use: `ros -m <name> -L sbcl-bin run`. (Quick edit: better use `ros dump` for saving images using roswell as it was pointed out to me)

Comment: What worked for me was `export SBCL_HOME=/usr/lib/sbcl/` (the one printed by `(sb-int:sbcl-homedir-pathname)` and not /usr/local/bin).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create executables, you could try the following:

```
(sb-ext:save-lisp-and-die 
  "core"
  :compression t
  ;; this is the main function:
  :toplevel (lambda () 
              (print "hell world")                                      
              0)
  :executable t)
```

With this you should be able to call `QUICKLOAD` as you wish. Maybe you want to checkout my extension to CL-PROJECT for creating executables: https://github.com/ritschmaster/cl-project

Comment: `:COMPRESSION` doesn't work on mine (not build with zlib support). I don't want standalone executable now. And I want sbcl to drop into REPL, adding toplevel function makes it to execute and exit sbcl.