# Don't know how to require sb-cltl2

Tags: common-lisp

I'm trying to run an executable with an Hunchentoot server and I'm getting (after an unusual high CPU usage):

```
<INFO> [17:55:14] weblocks/server server.lisp (start) -   
Starting weblocks WEBLOCKS/SERVER::PORT: 40001   
WEBLOCKS/SERVER::SERVER-TYPE: :HUNCHENTOOT DEBUG: T 

debugger invoked on a SB-INT:EXTENSION-FAILURE in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {1008C1EA13}>:
Don't know how to REQUIRE sb-cltl2.
```

Do you have any idea what's going on ? It works correctly on Slime where I use the `start` function.

(sbcl manual: http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Customization-Hooks-for-Users)

In the `main` entry point, I try to capture the running thread so that I keep the server running on the foreground ([my notes](https://lisp-journey.gitlab.io/web-dev/#shipping)). This pattern worked with another clack-based web framework.

```
(defun start ()
  (weblocks/debug:on)
  (weblocks/server:start :port *port*))

(defun main ()
  (defvar *port* (find-port:find-port))
  (start)
  (handler-case (bt:join-thread (find-if (lambda (th)
                                             (search "hunchentoot" (bt:thread-name th)))
                                         (bt:all-threads)))
    (#+sbcl sb-sys:interactive-interrupt
      #+ccl  ccl:interrupt-signal-condition
      #+clisp system::simple-interrupt-condition
      #+ecl ext:interactive-interrupt
      #+allegro excl:interrupt-signal
      () (progn
           (format *error-output* "Aborting.~&")
           (uiop:quit 1))
    ;; for others, unhandled errors (we might want to do the same).
    (error (c) (format t "Woops, an unknown error occured:~&~a~&" c)))))
```

Or any indication of what could be the cause ?

Thanks again.

(I'm using [40ants' weblocks:reblocks branch](https://github.com/40ants/weblocks))

SBCL Debian 1.2.4

**edit** I tried

```
export SBCL_HOME=/usr/local/lib/sbcl/
```

I build with

```
build:
    $(LISP) --quit \
        --eval '(ql:quickload "foo")' \
        --eval '(require :sb-cltl2)' \
        --eval '(asdf:make :foo)'
```

=>

```
fatal error encountered in SBCL pid 25248(tid 140737353910016):
can't load .core for different runtime, sorry
Welcome to LDB, a low-level debugger for the Lisp runtime environment. 
ldb>
```

Comment: Might be related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/39133421/124319

Comment: Looks like it is. I set `SBCL_HOME` to `/usr/local/lib/sbcl/` or `…/contrib` and `require`d `sb-cltl2` before building the executable with no success.

Comment: Maybe there are different versions SBCL installed, or a core generated with a previous version? Not sure how to replicate this.

Comment: There's only one `which sbcl`… and one in roswell's path. However how can I check this core thing ? A quick search and manual overview didn't throw anything obvious.

Comment: Can you check the value of `(SB-INT:SBCL-HOMEDIR-PATHNAME)` in both environments?

Comment: @coredump in Slime: `#P"/usr//lib/sbcl/"` (and `14`) which is weird, in my main function: `#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {1008C26A13}>:
  The variable SB-INT:SBCL-HOMEDIR-PATHNAME is unbound.`. It seems I miss all the contribs. It's the first time it happens :/

Comment: *The **variable** SB-INT:SBCL-HOMEDIR-PATHNAME is unbound*? maybe you did not call it as a function? Are you using Docker to setup the system?

Comment: damn sorry, it is `NIL`. No I am not using docker. Debian's SBCL 1.2.4.

Comment: Given the path `/usr/lib/sbcl/` under Slime, I would try to set `SBCL_HOME` to that value (location of SBCL installed by Apt?) instead of `/usr/local/lib/sbcl/` (the one installed by Ros?).

Comment: It works. In your answer would you expand a bit on your reasoning ? Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following environment failed:

```
export SBCL_HOME=/usr/local/lib/sbcl/
```

The error message tells us the following:

> can't load .core for different runtime, sorry

Apparently the SBCL you ran used the given `SBCL_HOME` to find its core file, but failed due to the core being generated by different version SBCL.
A quick look at SBCL's source (starting from `require`) shows that the underlying function `#'SB-INT:SBCL-HOMEDIR-PATHNAME` is called to determine the installation path.

It looks like the one installed from the Debian package was installed in `/usr/lib/sbcl/`. The core file was easily found when starting Slime. You also had another version of SBCL in `~/.roswell/`, but I guess you also ran `ros install` which installed it under `/usr/local/lib/sbcl` (`/usr/local/` is for software that is not managed by the system).

Starting the roswell one when setting `SBCL_HOME` to the directory of the Debian one provoked the error about the incompatible core file (I guess).

*What remains suprising is that `(SB-INT:SBCL-HOMEDIR-PATHNAME)` returns nil when starting your main function.*

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was complaining about `sb-concurrency`. This was with a Clack/Woo combination. I was being told:

> Don't know how to REQUIRE sb-concurrency

Thanks to this post and [this related one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39133421/how-to-properly-save-common-lisp-image-using-sbcl), I solved the issue by explicitly depending on `sb-concurrency` within my `.asd` file. After that, I didn't need to do anything special in my source files; compiled executables "just worked" after that.